# Select and map over the values inside an observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-observables

I am trying to select and map the values of an observable w/o subscription?

**Question:**

**What are the operators to select `doggo[documents]` and map out `blocks` w/o breaking the Observable?**

from:

```
this.doggos.getDoggos().subscribe((doggos) => {
      this.galleryItems = doggos['documents'].map(d => d.blocks);
    });
```

to:

```
this.galleryItemsObs  = this.doggos.getDoggos().pipe(...);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `map`!

```
this.doggos.getDoggos().map((doggos) => {
  return doggos['documents'].map(d => d.blocks);
});
```